# Generalizing Data Communication with Sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I have to send data using Sockets. My problem is that I don't always know which type of data i'm going to send and read. Which is the best way to to generalize data communication with Java Sockets?

Comment: What do you know ? What do you do with the data on the other side ? If you're doing Java only, and both client and server know all the possible classes, then java serialization may be good ... there are general binary protocols, like Protocol Buffers, but nowadays most people just serialize to JSON (with something like Jackson) and deserialize from json on the other side

Comment: java data communication using sockets is already generalized in byte streams. Whatever data type you need to communicate, you have to be able to serialize it before sending and deserialize it after receiving